# VBA array value

Tags: arrays, vba, ms-word

I have problem with passing data from txt file to array. I have word document which needs to be filled with data from txt file.

```
Private Function ReadString() As String
Dim textArray() As String
Dim data As String
Open "C:\Data\XFile.ini" For Input As #1
    r = 0
    Do Until EOF(1)
    ReDim textArray(0 To r)
    Line Input #1, data
    textArray(r) = data
    r = r + 1
    Loop
    ReadString = textArray(77)
    ' MsgBox ReadString
    ' MsgBox "After"
    Close #1
End Function
```

I need data from line 78, but something is wrong in my code and data is not passed from file to array. If anybody can point out problem I would be very thankful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `ReDim Preserve` to preserve the data in the array when you `ReDim` it.  Otherwise, the array will be erased.

```
Private Function ReadString() As String
    Dim data As String, textArray() As String
    Dim n As Long
    ReDim textArray(0)
    Open "C:\Data\XFile.ini" For Input As #1

    Do Until EOF(1)
        ReDim Preserve textArray(count)
        n = n + 1
        Line Input #1, data
        textArray(n) = data
        r = r + 1
    Loop
    Close #1
    ReadString = textArray(77)
End Function
```

You could also use an ArrayList to store your data.

```
Private Function ReadString2() As String
    Dim data As String
    Dim list As Object
    Set list = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")

    Open "C:\Data\XFile.ini" For Input As #1
    Do Until EOF(1)
        ReDim Preserve textArray(count)
        Line Input #1, data
        list.Add data
    Loop
    Close #1
    ReadString = list(77)
End Function
```

To extract the whole array use `textArray = list.ToArray`.

Comment: @YowE3K thanks again.   I forgot that textArray was 0 based.